# How to change a variables value within a async func?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to set the value of an array to a couple things stored in my firebase firestore. I am then trying to set the array to a UIPicker. Please tell me what is wrong with my func declaration:

```
func getDropDownOptions(completion: @escaping (_ in1: String,_ in2: String,_ in3: String,_ in4: String,_ in5: String) -> Void)
```

or my calling of the funtion:

```
getDropDownOptions { (in1, in2, in3, in4, in5) in
            if in1 == "nil" {
                self.errorLabel.text = "Please add an intrest to your profile"
                return
            } else if in2 == "nil" {

                return self.sportPickerData = [in1, in2]
            } else if in3 == "nil" {

                return self.sportPickerData = [in1, in2, in3]
            } else if in4 == "nil" {
                return self.sportPickerData = [in1, in2, in3, in4]
            } else {
                return self.sportPickerData = [in1, in2, in3, in4, in5]
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is it doing wrong? What should it be doing? You shouldn't be trying to `return` the result of an assignment operator, try removing those and see if it helps.

Comment: Just return the array you want.  Returning the assignment will return `void`, not the array.

Answer (score 1):

If the completion is called on a background thread, then you need to dispatch back to the main thread to change the UI.

```
// if you are in a background thread, then ...
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Update UI here
}
```

So, for the error label, you should definitely do this.  For the other variables, you could set them, but if they cause UI change, you should probably do that in the main thread.

For example:

```
// if you are in a background thread, then ...
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // Update UI here
    self.errorLabel.text = "Please add an intrest to your profile"
}
```

Comment: I put in sample code -- but, this might not solve your problem -- it is _a problem_, but maybe not the only one.  You haven't told us what is happening that is wrong